# bootstrap-4 card not filling height to bottom of row

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on some code in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/8g034hyk/23/
And have been having trouble getting one card to be more responsive.

As you can see in this image, the card3 data box will expand to fit the bottom of the row where the card2 data box ends (Great!)

[image]

But if the card3data box goes on for longer, to the point where it goes beyond the end of card2data box,

[image]

So what I've been trying to fix in the jfiddle all day today is to make it so my card2data box will expand it's height to meet the card3data box, eliminating the empty space and aligning both bottoms of card2 and card2 boxes to meet at the same point.

The closest I've gotten is from adding `style="height: 100%"`, but the only problem is that that causes the box to expand past the point I'm trying to get it to end at. I'm sure there is some simple bootstrap4 / html / js / css solution to achieve what I'm looking for, and I'd appreciate any help finding it! Thanks

Comment: You need these two classes `d-flex flex-column` on the first `.col` https://jsfiddle.net/knwpgdhc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following css and html ( added class for the first col ).

**CSS**

```
.first-row{
    max-height: max-content;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
            <!-- left column -->
    <div class="col  d-flex flex-column">
        <!-- card 1 (top) -->
        <div class="col d-flex first-row">
            <div class="card w-100">
                card 1 data <br>
                card 1 data <br>
                card 1 data <br>
                card 1 data <br>
                card 1 data <br>
                card 1 data <br>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- ./top card 1 -->
        <br>
        <!-- card 2 (bottom) -->
        <div class="col d-flex"> <!-- TRIED adding style="height: 100%" but this expands to very bottom -->
            <div class="card w-100 ">
              card 2 data <br>

                card 2 data <br>
                card 2 data <br>
                card 2 data <br>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- ./bottom card 2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- right column -->
    <div class="col d-flex">
      <div class="col d-flex">
        <!-- card 3 (long) -->
        <div class="card w-100 h-100" style="height:100%">
                card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>
                card 3 data <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div> <!-- ./card 3 -->
<br>
<!-- bottom row (table) -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col ">
            <div class="card w-100">
                card 4 data <br>
                card 4 data <br>
                card 4 data <br>
                card 4 data <br>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- ./top card -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Please check your fiddle, I saved my code.